# Can't call the webmethod using user control

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, webmethod

I'm creating a modal when I click I will pass the id and action to the serverside to save a logs.

Here is my sample code but can't get it to work. I'm using a usercontrol.

```
$("a.modal_show2").click(function () {
    $(this).each(function () {
        if ($(this)) {
            var storecheckid = $(this).attr("id");
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "TalkTalk.aspx/saveLogs",
                data: {
                    action: 'video_tag',
                    clickedlinktag: storecheckid
                },                      
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string saveLogs(string action, string clickedlinktag)
{
    DataHelper.InsertLogs("TalkTalk", Convert.ToInt16(clickedlinktag), Convert.ToInt16(TwwId));
    return clickedlinktag;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: "can't get it to work" isn't an error message or problem statement. Please clarify what the difficulty is. What debugging have you done to try and narrow down the problem? On the face of it, there's not much which is obviously wrong with your code. We need some clues. BTW as an aside, `$(this).each` in your code really makes no sense. `this` will always be a single element, it makes no sense to try and loop through it. It probably works since it will just loop once and stop, but it's not a logical bit of code.

Comment: `if ($(this)) {` within it is also meaningless. If `this` didn't exist then the code would have crashed on the previous line at the loop. But also, the JS engine will make sure that's always populated with something.

Comment: See [this example](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Call-ASPNet-Page-Method-using-jQuery-AJAX-Example.aspx). Notice the data type, and the "stringified" format of the `data` property.

Comment: there is no error and the webmethod is not trigger.

($(this)) is the object i click in modal.
var storecheckid is the id of the image 
it has a value.
but when passing a varaiable to the serverside i cannot trigger the function and save it to database

Comment: In that case, have you checked...does the "click" trigger? Does the AJAX method execute? Does any request ever get made? If not, then you'll need to work out why. Could be to do with the redundant code I mentioned. If it does get made, what response do you get? Are there any errors logged on the server side? As I said before, "Cannot" is not an error message. Again, you need to actually debug your code thoroughly...this should all be standard work you do whenever a problem happens. Work through the process of your code logically from beginning to end and see where it starts to go wrong.

Comment: try using [HttpPost] instead of [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]. might help

Comment: yes the ajax method execute success. no errors logged on the server side.
@ADyson

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan can you please elaborate and give some examples about the HttpPost . not quite familiar with httppost.
thanks

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan that would apply if OP is using ASP.NET MVC or Web API. WebMethod is used together with ASP.NET WebForms. It's not actually stated in the question which framework is being used. Your comment would be better posed as a question rather than a suggestion with no explanation. Perhaps Ian can clarify.

Comment: @IanFrancisDAVOCOL If the AJAX returns a success status ("200 OK", I assume?), then what is contained within the "Response" tab of that request? Is it what you expected? If the call was successful, it's hard to understand how it doesn't trigger the WebMethod code. This sounds like a very odd and unlikely scenario.

Comment: @ADyson yes the ajax returns a sucess status but it does'nt trigger the webmethod and save.

Comment: So again, what is in the response when it comes back? Are you sure the URL is correct?

Comment: ok i change the code in the data section to
data: '{clickedlinktag: "' + storecheckid + '" }'

it worked.
and when changed it to two variables it doesn't worked again
data: '{clickedlinktag: "' + storecheckid + '", LogPaged : "' + logPage + '" }',

Comment: @IanFrancisDAVOCOL What if you encapsulate the property names in quotes: `'{"clickedlinktag": "' + storecheckid + '", "LogPaged" : "' + logPage + '" }'`

Comment: don't build your JSON by hand like that - in the original code page you were making a JS object correctly. It's just possible that for the WebMethod to accept it you need to stringify it as per wazz's answer below. Also your stated method accepts "action" and "clickedlinktag" as the parameters, but now you seem to be randomly sending a "LogPaged" instead...it won't like it if you supply parameters which don't match its expectations. Have you changed your other code in the meantime? Don't forget to update your question if you change relevant things, we are not mind-readers.

Comment: sorry in the code i rename the parameters. 
Thanks @ADyson

Answer (score 1):

```
data: JSON.stringify({ action: 'video_tag', clickedlinktag: storecheckid })

// response is a wrapper for your data. your data is in `d`.
success: function (response) {
    console.log(response.d);
}
```

Comment: I think the first part of your answer is good. However `dataType: "json"` is not a good idea. The WebMethod clearly returns a plain-text string and not any JSON.

Comment: Yeah, not really sure why I did that. Just not used to seeing 'text' i think.

Comment: Updated answer.